# App iOS BLE is not getting reconnected after a disconnection if a long time happen

Tags: ios, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

User history: The user connects the app with the peripheral device, after a successful connection and after subscribing all the characteristic properly, the user puts the app in the background. The user leaves the rage area of the peripheral device and a connection happen.

Test case: When the user comes again and enters to the BLE range of the peripheral device, the OS should wake app the app and reconnect the app properly.

Solution: I'm using Support for State Preservation and Restoration, as the documentation: https://apple.co/2UM6xmi
The reconnection happens when only: when the app is killed by the system and the willRestore method is called, and the same happens when I restart the device.

Problem: When the user leaves the BLE range-area the disconnection happens but after 20 minutes of disconnection and going back to the range-area of the BLE peripheral the reconnection is not happening.

Is like the app is suspended, the BLE documentation says that in this case ( https://apple.co/2IpNffT ), the app is not going to restore the BLE central state, but now the question is if I kill the app  programmatically after a disconnection, the method willRestore will be called only once and if there is not any BLE peripheral the connection won't happen anyway.

There is any way to achieve this? accordingly, to the documentation (in the first link) this case is possible to address, the documentation talks about a hypothetical app for an automatic door using BLE. But I have been tried this approach for a couple of days without any success, do you have any suggestion?

This is the code:

In the controller that scans the peripherials:

I initialize the central manager:

```
 let options = [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: "someIdentifier"]
        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue:nil, options: options)
```

in willRestoreState method:

```
 func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {
        let peripherals = dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] as! NSArray
        print(peripherals.debugDescription)
        if(peripherals.count > 0){
            let peripheral = peripherals.object(at: 0) as! CBPeripheral
            self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral
            self.discoveredPeripheral!.delegate = self
            self.connectingPeripherals.append(self.discoveredPeripheral!)
            self.centralManager!.connect(self.discoveredPeripheral!, options: nil)
        }else{
            scan()
        }
}
```

didConnect method:

```
 func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        savePeripheral(peripheral: peripheral)
        self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral
        self.discoveredPeripheral!.delegate = self
        currentState = STATE_CONNECTED
         self.discoveredPeripheral!.discoverServices([CBUUID(string: TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID)])
        eventsToSubscribe = [CBUUID(string: SOME_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)]
    }
```

The scenarios that are working are these:

1- The app is killed with the statement:   kill(getpid(), SIGKILL); it is reconnecting again.

2- The device is restarted after 1 or 2 minutes, it is reconnected.

3- Disconnection happens because we are out of range of the Bluetooth and the device enters in the range again within the first 5~10 minutes, then the device is reconnected.

The scenario that doesn't work:

1- If a disconnection happens because we are out of range of the Bluetooth and the device enters in the range again 10 minutes later the device won't be reconnected again.

Does someone have any clue what is happening here?

Thanks so much, I appreciate the support.

Comment: Can you show the code that is in your `didDisconnect` delegate method? - you should call `connect` in this method.

Comment: I discovered why it didn't work, the problem actually was that I was using an android device as a peripheral identifier with an app that I made to simulate a real peripheral. Because is in Android, the Android OS is changing the peripheral identifier when there is no connection in the Bluetooth. That is why the app is not able to find the peripheral and reconnect with it after 10 minutes, with the real peripheral the app is working fine, I tested it after 10 hours and is working great, the reconnection happens.